# Depeloping firefox addon - hide all toolbars

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

My extension opens in a new FF tab. I would like all toolbars(exept for tabbar) be hidden when the tab is active.
What I want is exactly how the standard FF addons tab works(tools->addons).

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this code into scratchpad with browser environment and run it:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
try {
    sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
} catch (ex) {}

var css = '';
css += 'toolbar { display: none }';
var cssEnc = encodeURIComponent(css);
    var newURIParam = {
        aURL: 'data:text/css,' + cssEnc,
        aOriginCharset: null,
        aBaseURI: null
}
var cssUri = Services.io.newURI(newURIParam.aURL, newURIParam.aOriginCharset, newURIParam.aBaseURI);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

to remove just run the `sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);`

Comment: It works in scratchpad. But how can I implement it in my extension?

Comment: I would have to see your addon. Is it on github?

Comment: You should be able to copy paste this into your adon though. Just remove the top `try` statement and when you want to remove it just use the `unregister` part. Although this will affect ALL windows, not just that window. You may want to load the css into the current window only. If this is the case let me know and I'll tell you the `loadSheet` method.

Comment: The stylesheet service is actually not a good choice for this kind of task, as it e.g. breaks *View*/*Toolbars* or interferes with other add-ons doing toolbar stuff.

Comment: Ah very right. But I thought he didn't want the view ability while his tab was focused, so as soon as he goes to another tab (or when he unregisters) it will be reflected correctly according to the view toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write what kind of extension you're developing... SDK or XUL.

In a XUL extension, first get all toolbars, then set `collapsed` according to your wishes.

Here is some same code.

```
function toggleToolbars() {
  // First get all toolbars (that are not the tab bar)
  var tbs = Array.filter(document.querySelectorAll('toolbar'), function (x) {
    return x.id != 'TabsToolbar';
  });
  // For each toolbar 
  for (var tb of tbs) {
    // Either un-collapse if we collapsed it.
    if (tb.getAttribute('my-addon-collapsed')) {
      tb.removeAttribute('collapsed');
      tb.removeAttribute('my-addon-collapsed');
    }
    // Or collapse other-wise, if not already collapsed
    else if (!tb.getAttribute('collapsed')) {
      tb.setAttribute('collapsed', 'true');
      tb.setAttribute('my-addon-collapsed', 'true');
    }
  }
}
```

You may wish to fixup the code to handle corner cases, such as the user manually restoring a toolbar, other add-ons add-on entirely new toolbars later and so on.

In an SDK add-on your will need to get to the actual `browser.xul` windows first. I'm sure how to do this is already somewhere on SO.